# Populate img source dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

What I have done is get my data back via ajax.  In that object I have string url's that I'm trying to assign to an image that is created.  I dont know excatly how to do it.  What I have tried is getting the data looping through creating my table rows / cells then finding the specific cell create an image object and assign the souce value from the from the data object.  Here is the code:

```
var imgAttr = [];
$.ajax({
    url: 'DAL/WebService1.asmx/RegisteredProducts',
    method: 'post',
    data: { pageNumber: currentPage, pageSize: 5 },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).each(function (index, d) {

            imgAttr = d.ImgUrl;

            $('#displayMe').append('<tr><td class="imageHolder"></td> <td> + d.id + </td></tr>');

            $('.imageHolder').each(function () {                
                var img = $('<img />', {
                    class: 'Myid',
                    src: imgUrl                                          
                    alt: 'Image'                        
                });
                $(this).html(img);

            });

          });

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: How about `$('#displayMe').append('<tr><td class="imageHolder"><img  class="Myid" src="'+imgUrl+'" alt="Image"></td> <td> + d.id + </td></tr>');` ?

Comment: Where is your `imgUrl` have been declared?

Comment: `src: imgAttr,` instead of `src: imgUrl `  ? (notice, comma sign is part of the code)

Comment: @Igor, Thanks man! That was terrible by me :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#displayMe').append('<tr><td class="imageHolder">' + 
  '<img src="' + d.ImgUrl + '" class="Myid" alt="Image"/>' +
  '</td> <td>' + d.id + '</td></tr>');
```

Simply use the above for your `$('#displayMe').append` line and remove `$('.imageHolder').each` part.

Comment: What will one do with this ? I hope you won't mind proving some explaination so that OP will get something out of it.